# Rotate Background Image of Div 90 Degrees using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transform

I have a div that looks something like this:

```
<p class="stepNode" aria-disabled="true" style="background: url(https://...jpg) 50% 50%;">
    <p class="stepLabel">
       <div> New Step</div>
     </p>
</p>
```

I want to rotate the background image within the div 90 degrees counterclockwise (without rotating the entire container ".stepNode".  **How can I do this using jQuery?**

Comment: You can't, as backgrounds can't be rotated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a :before to a container which contains the background (See [this](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/) for more information).

```
.stepNode:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
    top: -50%;
    left: -50%;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url(some-background-url-here) 40% 50% no-repeat;
```

Then you make a css class that contains the rotate properties.

```
.transform:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-30deg);
    transform: rotate(-30deg);
}
```

And via jquery, you can add the class:

```
$(".stepNode").addClass("transform");
```

Also, you can set a transition time, to add animation (put this in .stepNode:before)

```
-webkit-transition: all 1s;
-moz-transition: all 1s;
-ms-transition: all 1s
-o-transition: all 1s;
transition: all 1s;
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q85k6/).

Edit: 90 degrees version: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q85k6/1/)

Comment: thanks for your help. I'm trying this out, but I need to set the background of the :before element dynamically.  any ideas?

Comment: Normally you would select the element and use $(selector).css(). But since we are using the pseudo-element, which is not part of the DOM, we can't select it with jQuery. So, instead, you can use     $("head").append() to directly add css to the html. Check the [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q85k6/2/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you would need to have two divs which are in absolute positioning. In containing the background image and one containing the text.

```
<div class="myRotate"></div>
<div class="myContent">
    <p class="stepNode" aria-disabled="true">
        <p class="stepLabel">
           <div> New Step</div>
        </p>
    </p>
</div>
```

Next you could attach a Jquery OnClick event on whatever element you want in order for the background to rotate.

```
$(function(){
    $('.myContent').click(function(){
        $('.myRotate').css({'-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(-90deg)',
                     '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(-90deg)',
                     '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(-90deg)',
                     'transform' : 'rotate(-90deg)'});
    });
});
```

Here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/knDn8/1/)

Comment: Note that this rotates the entire element.